# Find a partial sum and estimate the error/remainder.

Tags: sequences-and-series

a) Find the partial sum $s_{10}$ of the series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^4}$$

So I got from a series calculator that it's about 1.082.

Estimate the error:

$$R_{10} \leq \int_{10}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^4} = \lim_{t \to \infty} \int_{10}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^4}dx = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{-1}{3x^3} \bigg\rbrack_{10}^{\infty} = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{-1}{3t^3} + \frac{1}{3*10^3} = \frac{1}{3000}$$

[image]

b) Use (3) with $n_{10}$ to give an improved estimate of the
sum.

[image]

$$s_{10} + \frac{1}{3*11^3} \leq s \leq s_{10} + \frac{1}{3000}$$

so the new estimate is an avg of 1.08225 and 1.08233 so = 1.08229

c) Find a value of n so that sn is within 0.00001 of the sum.

Can I do this?

formula for error:

$$\frac{1}{3n^{10}}$$

so

$$\frac{1}{3n^{10}} \lt 0.00001$$

so $n \approx 182.57$ so $n \gt 183$

Is that right?

Comment: it might help to note that $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac1{n^4}=\frac{\pi^4}{90}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your formula for $R_n$ based on you integration should be
$$R_n \leq \frac{1}{3n^3}.$$
So, let $$\frac{1}{3n^3} < 0.00001,$$
and solve for $n$.  If you are unsure, you can check your error with the exact value of the sum: $\frac{\pi^4}{90}.$